# I need a javascript command that can check a speciffic checkbox from html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="checkbox_design">
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <label for="acord_regulament">
      Am luat la cunoștință
      <a href="https://www.bereciucas.ro/static/pdf/regulament_premii.pdf" target="_blank">
        Regulamentul Oficial al Campaniei
      </a>
      .
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acord_regulament" value="1" id="acord_regulament" class="validate[required] req_checkbox" tabindex="6">
  </div>
```

I need the checkbox to be checked via JavaScript.

I just began learning javascript so this is new for me. When that checkbox is checked it looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox_design">
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <label for="acord_regulament" class="checked">
      Am luat la cunoștință
      <a href="https://www.bereciucas.ro/static/pdf/regulament_premii.pdf" target="_blank">
        Regulamentul Oficial al Campaniei
      </a>
      .
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acord_regulament" value="1" id="acord_regulament" class="validate[required] req_checkbox noinputError" tabindex="6">
  </div>
```

Comment: While I appreciate that you're new to JavaScript we do expect you to have made some effort at solving your own problem(s); where did you get stuck? What did you attempt? How did your attempt(s) fail?

Comment: 10 attempts, and this is the last step for today's work.
I work as a pentester , and i need to inject a javascript that checks that box.

Comment: So how far did you get in your five attempts? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong? Where is your attempted code? Please, add these details to the question; you should probably also take the [tour] and check out the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidance.

Comment: `document.getElementById("acord_regulament").checked = true;`

Comment: I can't find the right javascript syntax for the code to work. 
I tried "document.getElementByClass('checkbox_design').checked = true;" for example.

Comment: @AdrianZimbran its getElementsByClassName and it returns an array. so just for working code it would be `document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox_design')[0].checked = true;`. That won't error but may not solve your issue either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the second HTML snippet doesn't actually add the `checked` attribute. Maybe this will point you in the right direction:

```js
document.getElementById('acord_regulament').classList.add('noinputError');
document.querySelector('label[for="acord_regulament"]').classList.add('checked');
document.getElementById('acord_regulament').checked = true; // this attribute actually marks the checkbox as checked

document.getElementById('output').innerText = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox_design')[0].outerHTML; // this line just displays the output
```

```css
#output {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox_design">
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <label for="acord_regulament">
      Am luat la cunoștință
      <a href="https://www.bereciucas.ro/static/pdf/regulament_premii.pdf" target="_blank">
        Regulamentul Oficial al Campaniei
      </a>
      .
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acord_regulament" value="1" id="acord_regulament" class="validate[required] req_checkbox" tabindex="6">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```